# node app can't find front end of project to serve

Tags: node.js, express, deployment

I have a node app which in development is usin 2 servers one for my node side and another for my react side. I am running this using a line in my package.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon --inspect-brk app.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

when I run `npm run dev`it all works, however when I run node start the server starts running however when you go to the `/` root url it gives a 404 status error. I assume that's because the app doesn't know where to look for the index.html file or how to kick off the app though I could be completely wrong.

my folder structure is:

[image]

As you can see my client folder holds all of the react stuff. the src is the uncompiled react and the build holds my actual index.html fil along with the static folder which holds the compiled react stuff :

[image]

so how do I get that to actually work or point me in the direction to look? I guess i've been spoiled with most apps just knowing out of the box how to do this.

UPDATE:
so i have 2 routes currently setup

```
//initiate route handlers
app.use('/login', require('./routes/authRoutes'));
app.use('/tiles', require('./routes/tileRoutes'));
```

inside of /login I have for example

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
some code here...
}
```

however going to either of those, so if I navigate to localhost:5000/login, I still get a 404 error

If I understand this correctly it works when I run npm run dev because 2 serves spin up. the one server handles all my node code and the second handles all my react code. However I don't want  to run 2 servers as my deployment to heroku definitely won't. So how do I merge to 2 so to speak?

Comment: This question should be about your actual server code (and should show the relevant code) that is meant to be responding to requests for the root URL.  node.js does not serve ANYTHING by default so if you expect an HTML page or Javascript file to be served in request to some URL, you have to have a route handler that makes that happen.  We can only really help you with this when you show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use express.static() function to host static files on your express server. See more here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html